# Gradle - hibernate tool not working

Tags: hibernate, gradle, ant

I'm trying to create a task to convert cfg to sql and I'm using hibernate 3.

My ant task for same looks like this -

```
ant {
    taskdef(name: 'hibernateTool',
    classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
    classpath: configurations.hibernatetool.asPath
    )
    hibernateTool(destdir: 'resources/b2c/hibernate/schema') {
    annotationconfiguration(configurationfile:      'resources/b2c/hibernate/hibernate.b2c.cfg.xml')
    hbm2ddl(export: true, outputfilename: 'db-b2c-update-ddl.sql')
    classpath {
        pathelement(path: 'classes')
        fileset(dir: '../intl_lib') {
        include(name: '*/.jar')
    }
    }
}
}
```

I have added the following dependencies for the same -

```
dependencies {
    hibernatetool group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-tools', version: '3.2.4.GA'
    hibernatetool group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '3.6.10.Final'
}
```

Applied plugin -

```
plugin: id "org.hibernate.gradle.tools" version "1.2.3"
```

Set configuration as -

```
configurations {
    hibernatetool
}
```

I'm getting the following error while running the task -

```
[ant:hibernateTool] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
[ant:hibernateTool] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[ant:hibernateTool] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Here is the stack trace for the same -

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1315)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1068)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 165 more
```

Any leads on this is appreciated.

Comment: What plugins are you loading for in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Its already there in the question, anyways "org.hibernate.gradle.tools" version "1.2.3" is the plugin I'm adding.

Comment: I should have been more specific. Can you post the section of your build file with the plugins declared?

Comment: plugins { id "org.hibernate.gradle.tools" version "1.2.3" id 'java' id 'eclipse' id 'idea' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following dependencies should fix the mentioned issue related to slf4j.

**hibernatetool group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.6'

hibernatetool group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version: '1.6.6'**

It would also be required to add this log4j dependency in order to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority this error.

**hibernatetool group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'**

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you have not pointed to the correct repository. If you check the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.hibernate.gradle.tools) page for Hibernate the following build information is provided. I am not sure which Gradle version you are using so I will provide the "all" version build.

In `gradle.build`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.hibernate.gradle.tools:hibernatetools-gradle-plugin:1.2.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.hibernate.gradle.tools"
```

This build will explicitly define not only the plugin but the repository to download the plugin from. Please try this method of applying the Hibernate plugin and see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm using Gradle 2.10. No luck with this, still the same error.

Comment: Unless you update your answer with the following I will not be able to help any further. Your complete `build.gradle` file formatted properly. This includes the task in question. The error message also indicates that you are simply dropping the ant configuration into Gradle instead of converting it.

Comment: If you are generating SQL from configuration files you may want to look into  Gradle [COPY](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) and [COPYSPEC](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) as it can be used with `filter` to replace text in files dynamically.